# shortcutting access to another class properties, best practices

Tags: c#, properties, getter

My app has a CurrentContext class, it provides access to properties used across the whole app (so there's no need to pass the objects via constructor parameters or methods).

Most of those properties do not change their value during a single session.

Because some classes use some of the properties quite often I decided to create properties inside them, now I'm refactoring my code so the access pattern everywhere is the same.

Which of the below pattern is a better practice?

What is the difference in memory usage or performance?

CurrentContext class:

```
public class CurrentContext
{
   public Document Doc {get; set}
   public LogFile LogFile {get; set;}
   public bool AbortFlag {get; set;}
}
```

Class accessing the properties of CurrentContext class:

Variant 1:

```
public class Example
{
   private Document Doc {get { return MyApp.CurrentContext.Doc; } }
   private LogFile LogFile {get { return MyApp.CurrentContext.LogFile; } }
   private bool AbortFlag {get { return MyApp.CurrentContext.AbortFlag; } }
}
```

Variant 2:

```
public class Example
{
   private Document Doc {get; }
   private LogFile LogFile {get; }
   private bool AbortFlag {get; }

   public Example()
   {
       Doc = MyApp.CurrentContext.Doc;
       LogFile = MyApp.CurrentContext.LogFile;
       AbortFlag = MyApp.CurrentContext.AbortFlag;
   }
}
```

Comment: what sort of app is this?

Comment: to be very specific, an Autodesk Revit add-on.

Comment: the variant 2 would generize a soild variable by compiler , so cause slightly more memory. the variant 1 is nothing more than a get-function , would return a 'real ' reference to its caller, which means even Doc was replaced by some new instance , variant 1 is able to find it , so this variant takes more instructions on machine code, implies slightly lower performance. I can not say which one is best, it depends on the restrictions on your application situation.

Comment: An additional point that could be considered: for both variants the dependency to the CurrentContext class is hardcoded

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on a false belief; that the only difference between both approaches is a supposedly gain (or loss) in performance. That is not true; the two options you are proposing have very different meanings.

The first will always return an updated value when the properties are accessed, the second will return the values at the time the object was created.

It’s up to you to decide which of the two is the correct approach. Performance wise the difference, if any, is absolutely insignificant unless the accessed properties themselves are expensive (which they shouldn’t if you follow best practices).

Were it my code, I’d probably push back on the whole set up. Repeating properties is boring and hard to maintain if the underlying object changes throughout the life of your application. I’d simply expose the object itself or if that’s not an option, I would expose a readonly interface.

Answer (score 0):

The first version better, because it is returned the current value. When the value of any  MyApp.CurrentContext.* variable is changing, your Example will also changing.

This version is little-bit slower, but in 99% percent this disadvantage is acceptable.

But please expression body member syntax. This syntax is designed for this case:

```
public class Example
{
   private Document Doc => MyApp.CurrentContext.Doc;
   private LogFile LogFile => MyApp.CurrentContext.LogFile;
   private bool AbortFlag => MyApp.CurrentContext.AbortFlag;
}
```

This code is more understandable.

Comment: Why is it better? If the property doesn’t change, is it better? Should the object always return updated values or should it return values on creation? If the property is very expensive even if it doesn’t change later on, is the user experience better paying the price on creation or on property access? Etc. Claiming betterness with no context whatsoever is premature at best.

Comment: If the property is changing there will be a inconsistent data in application context. I think is not acceptable.  In my answer I also wrote the in 99% percent case the performance lost is acceptable.  Of course when the property calculation is is very expensive the cache mechanism is need. But this cache is also must be in MyApp.CurrrentContext.DocCahced or something like this.  The Original question was: "Shortcut for other class member".  The expression body member syntax is especially designed for it.

Comment: Why? Don’t *assume*  things, answer with factual data. What if the object is some kind of snapshot? Does it then make sense to update values? *Better* depends on what the object is supposed to do. You don’t know what it does, so don’t judge the betterness; simply point out the differences between approaches.

Comment: Actually I pointed that most of the properties don't change their values during one session. Some do, so if I want to be consistent across the whole app I need to pick variant 1. Thanks for pointing at the new "=>" syntax!

Comment: The question was exactly : "shortcutting access to another class properties, best practices". And my answer is contains the the best practice for short-cutting. I did not assume anything.  The expression body member syntax is the right answer, because it is designed for this case

Comment: InBetween, Please do not downvote my answer, just because you do wanted.  My answer was a useful answer for the question. Thx :)